# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service .\geckodriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225595

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I been trying to make Instapy work but struck with this error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service .\geckodriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225595
```

Here is some information about things I have already done;

1. Download latest version for `GeckoDriver`.
2. Download latest version of `FireFox`.
3. Installed `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015`

Waiting keenly for solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service .\geckodriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225595
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* unexpectedly exited.

---

### Status code: 3221225595

As per the documentation in [Getting error Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225595](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1672) `Status Code 3221225477` is raised in absence of **VCRUNTIME140.dll**.

[image: VCRUNTIME140_dll]

As of now you will need to install *Microsoft Visual Studio redistributable runtime* on all your Windows test machines for geckodriver to work.

> This issue was discussed and tracked in *Bugzilla* through [Geckodriver windows binaries don't run anymore without having the Microsoft MSCV runtime installed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1584530).

---

### Outro

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [geckodriver requires Microsoft MSVC runtime to be installed on Windows](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1617)

Comment: Well I deleted MVS redistributable and installed 64 bit version of Gecko driver, and now the above mentioned error is gone, but there is another error saying,
'Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities'
P.S: I'm trying to use Instapy

Comment: @ASADHAMEED That's a different error all together. I'm afraid, you may have to raise a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: But installing MCV runtime didn't solve my problem |:

Comment: I've got the same problem with ubuntu: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6"